# Error adjusting column name in a dataset in R

Tags: r

Can you help me to adjust the code below, as I am not able to properly rename the columns of my data.

```
df<-structure(c(10839.2814863901, 2, 10227.8884004375, 187965), .Dim = c(1L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("X", "Y", "Z", 
"W")))

            X Y        Z      W
[1,] 10839.28 2 10227.89 187965

df1<-df[,2:4] 

    Y         Z         W 
 2.00  10227.89 187965.00 

colnames(df1) = c("Name1","Name2","Name3")

Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3")) : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `df` is not actually a data frame; `df` is a numeric matrix. When you subset the numeric matrix, it creates a numeric vector which does not take column names. You can fix things by converting `df` to a data frame.

```
df<-structure(c(10839.2814863901, 2, 10227.8884004375, 187965), .Dim = c(1L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("X", "Y", "Z", 
"W")))

df <- as.data.frame(df)

df1<- df[,2:4]

colnames(df1) <- c("Name1","Name2","Name3")
```